# jQuery card flip requires two clicks to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click, I want the clicked card to flip and reveal the backside. Everything is working smoothly, except for the fact that after the first click, two clicks are required to get the desired functionality.

The problem is that I would like this to only work with one click. I am very new to jQuery, so I'm expecting that this is probably a basic issue that I'm overlooking.

Here is the jQuery:

```js
function flip() {
  jQuery('.flip').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
}
```

```css
.ot-front {
  background-color: blue;
}

.ot-back {
  background-color: red;
}

.team-member {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .ot-back {
  background: #eee;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-members">
  <div class="team-member flip">
    <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
      <div class="ot-front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="ot-back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-member flip">
    <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
      <div class="ot-front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="ot-back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-member flip">
    <div class="card" onclick="flip()">
      <div class="ot-front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="ot-back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are new to jQuery anyway, abandon it now. It's cancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to implement it like this:

```
function flip(wrapperContainingElementToFlip) {
    wrapperContainingElementToFlip.find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}

jQuery('.flip').click(function () {
    flip($(this));
});
```

You will bind the click when the script is loaded.

You could also bind the click eventhandler on page load, by wrapping your code in a page load event handler, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Put your code here
});
```

By implementing your code as above, when clicking the element, a function will be called. The click event will be bound before calling the flip function, and will therefore execute.

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up replacing the function that was wrapping my code with the page load event handler, and that solved the issue I was having. Here is the updated jQuery:
https://codepen.io/jasonlively/pen/xWLYqm

Comment: You're most welcome :). Glad I could help. An upvote/accept would be greatly appreciated because of future reference for StackOverflow users with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the fact, that you wrapped your jQuery into a function.
So for this to work, you need to click once to call a function to work, and then another one, for jQuery function to work.

Try deleting the outer `function flip()` and see if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the outer function. It should look something like this:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

It does work just fine in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is doubled. You invoke `flip` on click and then subscribe to `click`, and then only do the flipping in the handler. Removing the outer function, the handlers in the HTML (and jQuery):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".card")).forEach(element =>
  element.addEventListener("click", () =>
    element.classList.toggle('flipped')
  )
);
```

```css
.ot-front {
    background-color: blue;
}
.ot-back {
    background-color: red;
}
.team-member {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card .ot-back {
    background: #eee;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

```html
<div class="team-members">
  <div class="team-member flip">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="ot-front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="ot-back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-member flip">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="ot-front">FRONT</div> 
      <div class="ot-back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-member flip">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="ot-front">FRONT</div>
      <div class="ot-back">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```